# It is safe to use lvh.me instead of localhost for testing?

Tags: dns, localhost, subdomain

I wonder whether is safe to use `lvh.me` instead of `localhost` when developing locally, since `lvh.me` must be resolved and the IP may change over time.

The goal of using `lvh.me` is to be able to handle subdomains, since `localhost` does not have top level domain.

Comment: I’m now using http://readme.localtest.me/ instead, because at least I can contact the maintainer.

Comment: `lvh.me` was just bought and do not work anymore

Comment: @RousseauAlexandre lvh.me works fine for me, fwiw.

Comment: Re: `lvh.me` having been bought and no longer working —there was an update at the time: https://twitter.com/levicook/status/1402069015338512385 (discoverable sifting through the responses below.)

Comment: If you own a domain you can point a subdomain wildcard A record to 127.0.0.1 to do the same thing

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Unless you are the maintainer of lvh.me, you can not be sure it will not disappear or change its RRs for lvh.me.

You can use `localhost.localdomain` instead of `localhost`, by adding the following lines in your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

This is better than using lvh.me because:

- you may not always have access to a DNS resolver, when developing
- lvm.me does not answer with a local IPv6 address corresponding to your local host, only with the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1
- some ISPs DNS resolvers block answers corresponding to private addresses space, for security purpose (to avoid leaking internal informations)

Since you said in a comment that you do not want to update the host file, you have no mean to be sure that lvh.me will always work for your developers. Therefore, to answer your question: it is not safe. You may register a domain for yourself, but as I said before, some resolvers will block answers corresponding to private addresses space.

Comment: The idea is not having to change the hosts file so you can clone the repo and start working.

Comment: Which repo? Your question did not mention this constraint.

Comment: That is because I ask whether it's safe, it is a general question. Unless there is some kind of compromise to keep that domain pointing to 127.0.0.1 it is not.

Comment: With the hosts file you can even manually point lvh.me to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *safe*?

Comment: today is the day you are absolutely right.

Comment: Nothing lasts forever!

Comment: I want it back up. It's parked free by Godaddy

Answer (score 15):

lvh.me was not resolving to 127.0.0.1 on June 7, 2021. Depending on DNS names you don't control comes with this kind of risk. Although the domain name was reinstated by the end of the day, this answer offers some alternatives to depending on someone else's DNS configurations.

Both Firefox and Google Chrome now treat `*.localhost` names like `localhost`. They also do the right thing with port numbers.

To test it yourself, start a local http server listening to port 8000:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

Then try these links

- http://example.localhost:8000
- http://other.localhost:8000
- http://sub.subdomain.localhost:8000

This trick does not help for command line programs. For example, this command will fail to resolve the host:

```
curl http://example.localhost:8000
```

Curl itself offers a lot of other tricks that might work for you if you need custom subdomains on the command line. For example, this trick works:

```
curl --resolve example.localhost:127.0.0.1 \
  http://example.localhost:8000
```

Also worth noting that a similar service is still available.

See https://readme.localtest.me.

One last alternative is to configure your own wildcard CNAME to resolve to 127.0.0.1. For example:

```
*.my.example.com.   1800    IN  CNAME   my.example.com.
my.example.com.     1800    IN  A       127.0.0.1
```

Comment: The original custodian of lvh.me gave up custody:  "I’m not planning to renew it; it’s not something I’ve personally used in more than a decade making it a strange out of pocket expense for me." — https://twitter.com/levicook/status/1401935705199185924

Comment: What about transferring the session to a subdomain with the `localhost`. When I had LVH it worked fine.

Comment: @jack-blank, I'll offer this educated guess (not sure what you mean by "transferring the session"). Short story: "yes." Longer story: web sessions depend on browser cookies for identification & browser cookies are scoped to domain names. Firefox & Chrome treat whatever.localhost like a domain name. So usual cookie rules apply. And server-side session data work as expected.

Comment: See https://twitter.com/levicook/status/1402069015338512385 -- lvh.me went down briefly in June 2021 (the time this answer was written) but it's back up now. He got donations to keep it running.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @AlexChaffee. I've edited this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

No because as of right now http://lvh.me has an expired domain.

[image]

Comment: See twitter.com/levicook/status/1402069015338512385 -- lvh.me went down briefly in June 2021 (the time this answer was written) but it's back up now. He got donations to keep it running. –

Answer (score 2):

Services like `lvh.me` or `localtest.me` are just DNS services, so the only thing you're publishing to them is the names or the hosts you're using. They *could* resolve to any IP at any time, but providing you use use them only for local tests with fake data, you'll be safe.

But what if they shut down the service? Again, since you should only use them for local tests, you'll get immediate feedback and can easily go back to using `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix if you don't want to rewrite your code is to open up hosts file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

paste in (replace yoursubdomain with what subdomain you're calling)

```
127.0.0.1 yoursubdomain.lvh.me
```

push `ctrl-x`
then `y`
then `enter`

Then you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing.  If it's local development then most the time yes, you can always resolve it if you want to check:

For linux or osx you can run this in terminal:

```
dig X.nip.io
```

It should always return 127.0.0.1.  So while it's not the "safest" way to do this (because you don't manage the DNS itself), I still use it frequently for some kind of resolving TLD when necessary.  Here's some valid reputable sites that are still around as of 2022/2023:

https://nip.io/

https://sslip.io/

Comment: This is no longer correct:  nslookup on x.nip.io results in `*** Can't find x.nip.io: No answer`.  But using 127.0.0.1.nip.io  works.

Answer (score -2):

You can just point your browser at `myproject.apps.localhost` or `www.example.net.localhost`.