# lvh.me stopped working for all systems with EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me
```

all was working fine for running projects with subdomains on local system,
in few minutes all stopped working with error

> puma/binder.rb:205:in `initialize': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "lvh.me" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

tried on multiple ports, systems & even different projects.

**all stopped working with very same error.**

any idea that what really happened?

**UPDATE: lvh.me seems to be up for sale, may it was publicly  available for access but now some one removed it (not sure)**

Comment: Looks like you're not alone. I'm not getting the error, but it just hangs when I try to access any subdomains using lvh.me and then times out. localhost obviously still works, but can't reach the subdomains from there.

Comment: Looks like an alternative here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584323/3911741

Comment: started working in next morning